# Changing the alpha texture format for a particle emitter

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Using `coco2d-iphone 1.0.1`, I have a continuous fire particle emitter. I would like to modify its alpha pixel format:

```
// Change format
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444];

// Make emitter
emitter = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:file];

// Change back
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
```

This doesn't work. I am well aware that `RGBA4444` should make my particles look weird, but they don't look weird - so I know that `RGBA4444` is not taking effect.

I suspect that it is because `RGBA8888` is being applied on all newly created particles. If I remove the `RGBA8888` line, it does work.

How can I make my emitter emit `RGBA4444`, regardless of the formats used in the rest of my game?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it works if you modify `CCParticleSystem.m`

That file loads the particle texture like this

```
CCTexture2D *tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:textureName];
```

So you change the format before and after that, and it works. Not sure why didn't it work in my example above though.